# Why is the Space Stone wrapped in a cube and called Tesseract?

Tags: marvel-cinematic-universe, avengers-infinity-war, captain-america-the-first-avenger

Did the tesseract storyline get introduced before the writers decided to introduce the Infinity War arc?

I'm just curious as to why the Space Stone was a cube, then crushed by Thanos to reveal the Space Stone in Infinity War.

Comment: Did you see Guardians of the Galaxy? It graphically shows what happens when you touch an infinity stone by hand and aren't someone like Thanos :) Storing the infinity stones in something that doesn't cause you to explosively disintegrate sounds like a pretty obvious idea.

Comment: Could just as well ask why the infinity stones are a gauntlet. You put them in things to make use of them.

Comment: The writers of __Infinity War__, who also wrote __Captain America: The First Avenger__ [revealed in an interview](https://youtu.be/31hGnh7elAU?t=1728): _"... we started with [Red Skull], 10 years ago. And he had the [Cosmic Cube](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cosmic_Cube#Fictional_item_history), which was then referred to sometimes as 'The Cosmic Cube', and __we didn’t know it was one of the Infinity Stones__.”_

Comment: @Luaan yes, I saw GotG, after I saw Infinity War. (Hadn't been keeping up, man what great movies I missed in theaters). I just remember really that the Tesseract/Cosmic Cube in Capt America: First Avenger destroyed Red Skull, but then I actually immediately recognized Red Skull in Infinity War, even before my buddy I had gone with. That was after the scene where Loki produces it for Thanos, and Thanos subsequently crushes the cube part to reveal the stone within. This is why I was asking, since I never followed any of the comics.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit in fairness, the infinity stones aren't a gauntlet. The gauntlet was specifically made to house them, and it was done later, so it's not part of the whole infinity stone package.

Comment: @vlaz That's exactly my point. The infinity stones are also not a cube, or a sceptre, or an android.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Initially I thought of something and it came VERY close to the actual answer(Marvel Wiki).

The space stone earlier existed as the stone itself (the pure form)
The Tesseract was built by Asgardians to control the power held within it.

The Asgardians used the Tesseract as a means to teleport apart from the bi-frost.
The space stone can not only teleport its beholder, but can alter space as well, create portals and even black holes.

The Asgardians at the time of Bor (father of Odin Borson and Thor's grandpa), sealed it in a cube shape, notice how Thor uses the device at the end of *Avengers* to use the Tesseract and is built exactly to hold a cube.

Comment: This answer will be better if you add some sources and/references from movies/comics

Comment: @KharoBangdo I really appreciate any edits,that make an answer better, I would have added exact lines and texts if time allowed me to do so.

Comment: Editing other people's answers to make substantial changes are discouraged on SE. Unless the answer is a 'Community Wiki'. Then anyone can freely edit & add more info to the answer. You can convert this answer to 'CW' by pressing edit & selecting 'Community Wiki'

Comment: Take the advice with a pinch of salt, ArSuKa.  Adding supporting materials that you have explicitly said you're comfortable with people adding, in support of the thesis of your answer, is _not_ making substantial changes.  Demanding that answers be made community wiki before one will give any assistance to others is not in the spirit of the rule and highly uncharitable to boot.  You will find in your wider StackExchange travels that there do exist people who do not demand that you disclaim credit for an answer before they will help you. https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/314064/

Answer (score 13):

Marvel had their comic books to draw from, in these the Terreract was already an established object as was the fact that it contained an Infinity Stone. but that was in the comics and not the MCU so i'll just stick to the MCU here.

The writers new the story arc they wanted to put into film, the Infinity War... *but it was impossible, they would never be able to pull of such a huge story-line with so many characters that are important to the story arc* from my understanding was very much the opinion of almost everyone at Marvel Studios. at least back when they made Captain America: the First Avenger which introduced the Tesseract.

However With the success of Iron Man, and with the grand an ideal goal a mere pipe dream, they laid out plans to see if they could bring all the main characters together for an Avengers Film. but even then they could see that maybe just maybe they might be able to dream. so why not use the Tesseract as the main plot point. if it goes no where then its not real matter, however if it works then they could continue that plan all the way forwards to Infinity War.

So yes they had it planned out, but only in a grand over arcing sort of plan, nothing set in stone.

**A Little evidence** be advised that finding contract information from way back in the beginning is troublesome to say the least...

[This site](https://screenrant.com/marvel-deals-contracts-secrets-facts-trivia/) among many, list the number of movies that certain actors have left in their contracts do not read if you don't want a few potential spoilers for avengers 4. but if offers a hint at how far back they planned the grand scheme, but Robert Downy Jr's contract has been extended a couple of times already, he originally only signed on for Iron Man... that's it... no cinematic universe deal. they renegotiated after the success of the first film.

Chris Evans (Captain America) on the other hand started out on a multi movie deal, so they at least hoped way back when they filmed the first Cap film that it would go as far as it has.

**How the Stones Appear**

Of the 6 infinity Stones, 3 of them appeared as something different at some point. its not just the Tesseract

- Space Stone - Inside the Tesseract
- Mind Stone - Inside the glowing center of Loki's Scepter
- Reality Stone - A Stone... that appears as a wavy floating red glowy thing

The other three have been introduced to us as having appearing in the "normal" gem appearance.

- Time Stone - Contained within the Eye of Agamoto, but still just the stone
- Power Stone - Contained with the Orb
- Soul Stone - Just as the stone... but somewhere hidden away somehow

So there is no fixed way they should appear if the writers wanted them to appear as something else for the sake of the plot then they did.

TLDR: They had hopes but no concrete plans, but they based a lot of it on the Comics in which the Space Stone was contained in the Tesseract.

Comment: Detailed answer, but to make this a better answer you may have to put up some references. shouldn't from comics as you seems to get it right. put valid references to make your theory more outstanding and concrete

Comment: @Vishwa, I agree references would be good, I just wish i could find some that were from credible sources, i made some of my comments based on how few films certain actors had on their contracts like Robert Downy Jr... but trying to find marvel contract information about RDJ and his contract earlier in the MCU is just about impossible as some many actors contracts are expiring soon. i even went onto page 3 of google!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: You can use that as a reference. find info about RDJ's contract and then you can show it as the foundation of your theory. you cna use anything as a base of your theory (anything doesnt mean gossips and non-canon sources). **PS:** *sometimes to get a source, I personally tried 10th page and Im sure others may've done the same if not more.* but really appreciating you trying hard mate..good work

Comment: “the Terreract was already an established object as was the fact that it contained an Infinity Stone” — until recently in the comics, the equivalent items were called [Infinity Gems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Infinity_Gems), not Infinity Stones.

Comment: minor quibble, Iron Man was a success well prior to Capt America: The First Avenger. The order of logic seems a bit wonky in this answer

Comment: @NKCampbell  adding another somethin to your quibble, Iron Man was a huge success, as a single movie(talking about the first one here), but as a franchise, Captain America is much more successful than IM

Comment: @NKCampbell, I'm confused by your "quibble", I didn't say that Iron Man wasn't a success until Cap1. It was the success of IM that ended up with Chris Evans having a multi-movie contract. "The order of logic seems a bit wonky" with your comment...

Comment: @Vishwa, As with my comment to NKCampbell, i didn't say it wasn't a success. just that when they started filming Iron Man, they didn't know how it was going to plan out, by the time it hit the box office they could see the potential and had grander plans.