# How could Red Skull use Tesseract as a power source?

Tags: marvel-cinematic-universe, captain-america-the-first-avenger

In *Captain America: The First Avenger* Red Skull used the Tesseract (Space stone) as a power source for Dr. Zola' weapons. But the tesseract isn't the Power stone. Then how could it be used as a power source?

Comment: See my comment to the question [Why is the Space Stone wrapped in a cube and called Tesseract?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/93350/why-is-the-space-stone-wrapped-in-a-cube-and-called-tesseract). Back then the writers didn't know that the [Cosmic Cube](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cosmic_Cube#Fictional_item_history) was going to be an Infinity Stone (in the comics _Cosmic Cubes_ are not the same as Infinity Stones).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just because it's not the Power Stone doesn't mean it doesn't have power or energy of its own.

The tesseract is a mystical object with enough power to *contain* an Infinity Stone, in fact the Space Stone and being able to use a *fraction* of the power would be quite something.

Indeed, Arnim Zola manages to tap into just a small fraction of the energy..

> ```
>               DR. ARNIM ZOLA
>          The exchange is stable. Amazing.
>          The energy we’ve just collected
>          could power a battleship. Ten
>          battleships.
>          (beat)
>          This will change the war.
> ```